# Android fail to get files in Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS

Tags: android, file, explorer

I'm trying to create a file explorer in my app', and I want to show only the contents in the Directory downloads.

The problem is, my code returns always null, when I want to get all files in this directory, I don't understand why :

```
File folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
Log.e("files", folder.listFiles().length + " items");
```

The app crash, because `folder.listFiles()` returns NULL, why? I wanted to be sure there is no problem with this directory, and indeed, it works, I can see files with other apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to resolve it :

add permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```